# Reverse Recursive CTE to find Parent value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have sample Parent Child data like below.

```
declare @tab table (Item varchar(10),Parent varchar(10),Priority int)

insert into @tab
SELECT 'A',NULL,3,0
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A1','A',2,1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A2','A',2,1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A11','A1',2,2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A12','A1',1,2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A21','A2',3,2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A22','A2',2,2

select * from @tab
```

now i need to traverse (Leaf node to subsequent Parent node) in reverse to set its Subsequent parent node Priority based on its all children minimum priority.

for example, for Children A11 and A12 minimum priority is 1 and that 1 should be set for A1.
for Children A21 and A22 minimum priority is 2 and that 2 should be set for A2.
now A1 priority is 1
A2 priority is 2

similarly for Children A1 and A2 minimum priority is 1 and that 1 should be set for A.

so expected output as below.

```
SELECT 'A',NULL,1,0
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A1','A',1,1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A2','A',2,1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A11','A1',2,2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A12','A1',1,2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A21','A2',3,2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A22','A2',2,2
```

Please guide me how to do it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your @tab table has 3 columns in definition, but the insert statement has 4. What is the meaning of the 4th column, level of the node?

Comment: There are two parts to each recursive query.  The anchor part defines the starting point.  In your case you want the leafs.  Write a query that finds these.  The second part is the recursive part.  Here you define how to move up the hierarchy.

Comment: @Kim Hoang : the 4th column is Level of me tree.

Comment: @Kim Hoang : the 4th column is Level of my tree calculated from previous CTE.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```
declare @tab table (Item varchar(10),Parent varchar(10),Priority int)


insert into @tab
SELECT 'A',NULL,3
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A1','A',2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A2','A',2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A11','A1',2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A12','A1',1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A21','A2',3
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A22','A2',2


;WITH RCTE AS
(
SELECT Item , Parent , Priority ,  1 AS Level
FROM @tab
WHERE Parent IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT Child.Item , Child.Parent , Child.Priority , Level+1
FROM @tab Child
INNER JOIN RCTE Parent
ON Parent.Item = Child.Parent

)

SELECT * FROM RCTE
```

Comment: @Kim Hoang : the 4th column is Level of me tree.

Comment: but where i am calculating minimum priority for parent based on its children.

Comment: What means the column Priority ?

Comment: for example, for Children A11 and A12 minimum priority is 1 and that 1 should be set for A1 (Its immediate parent). for Children A21 and A22 minimum priority is 2 and that 2 should be set for A2. now A1 priority is 1 A2 priority is 2 so min of these should be set for A. but if minimum priority of children is greater than its parent priority then we leave parent priority as is.

Comment: for example if A11 priority is 2 and A12 priority is 3, then MIN of these two is 2 but its parent A1 priority is 1 then we leave as 1

Comment: It's not possible using CTE to do this

Comment: so looping is the only option to do this.please let me know if you find any better solution

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what was the last field in your union all query so I excluded that.

The answer is simple, look in the last query.

```
create table #tab (Item varchar(10),Parent varchar(10), Priority int)


insert into #tab 
SELECT 'A',NULL,3
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A1','A',1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A2','A',2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A11','A1',2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A12','A1',1
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A21','A2',3
UNION ALL
SELECT 'A22','A2',2


SELECT 
    Item , 
    Parent , 
    coalesce((select min(Priority) from #tab b where b.parent  = a.item),a.priority) as [priority]
FROM 
    #tab a
```

Comment: the 4th column is Level of my tree calculated from previous CTE

Comment: seems its fine. just a simple query will it handle any number of levels.

Comment: @LearnSQL , If the answer helped you. Make it useful please :)